# How to redirect root web site to site collection

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2010, alternate-access-mappings

I'm having quite a hard time figuring out this problem and I need your help. Here's the scenario:

I have a sharepoint 2010 web application on my port 80. This has 2 site collections, the root, and the /sites/official. My problem is: The root site is empty, but in the future it will be my something (I don't know what yet), but my other site collection is ready to go and I already have an Internet address for it.

What I want to do is configure everything in way that I can type `http://contoso.com` and get as response my sub-site (yes, its a kind of redirect)...

how can I do it? What and where should I configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add content editor webpart  on your root site collection and put this javascript in that webpart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://contoso.com/sites/official"
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS manager
2. Right click on your SharePoint website -> `Properties`
3. Go to tab `Home Directory`
4. Choose `A redirection to a URL`
5. fill the URL for redirection. for example: `http://contoso.com/sites/official`

Notes:

- Make sure to check `A Directory below URL entered` to avoid redirect loop
- Link to another thread might interest the reader - [immediate redirect page in sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/immediate-redirect-page-in-sharepoint?newreg=abbb93ea53c04f718d49b56abd1c08e6)

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add alternate access mapping for the sub-site collection from the central administration.

Central Administration > Application Management > Web Applications > Configure alternate access mappings